# AWS ec2 root volume increase: Expanding elastic root volume on aws ubuntu instance not working

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I've followed [aws doc for expanding elastic root volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html)
 and got my root volume size increased from 8 GB to 20 GB, which i confirmed using `lsblk`.

`NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  20G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /`

But updated size not reflecting in the `df -h` command, even after i explicitly resize the device using the `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` command as my file system type is `ext4` which i checked using `sudo file -s /dev/xvd*` command. `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` command giving below output :-

> sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1 resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014) The
>   filesystem is already 2096635 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

Let me know, what i need to do for OS to pickup the size in my volume.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html

Comment: Hi Amit, how you solved this issue. I'm facing the exact same problem now. Can you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/dev/xvda1` is an 8 GiB partition on a 20 GiB device and there are no other partitions on the volume. In this case, the partition must be [resized](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/storage_expand_partition.html) in order to use the remaining space on the volume.

After you resize the partition, you can extend the file system (via `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1`) to occupy all of the space on the partition.

Comment: I went through the doc which you mentioned, but procedure is very complex , if there is any easy to follow commands/doc are there , it will be useful. i am sure lots of people have faced this issue and lost into the complex documentation.

Comment: I agree that the process can be complex for root partitions at this stage. Even AWS admits that: *"If the partition you need to resize is the root partition for an instance, the process becomes more complicated..."*. I do hope AWS would make the process much simpler for us in the future though.

Comment: The complexity of the procedure has absolutely nothing to do with AWS.  Re-partitioning the boot disk with the root volume on it -- aside from usually being the wrong solution -- is an intrinsically complex task.

Answer (score 21):

The reason for your output is because you are missing a step.

> The resize2fs program does not manipulate the size of partitions. If you wish to enlarge a filesystem, you must make sure you can expand the size of the underlying partition first... https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs

Once you've increased the size of your volume either from using the AWS Console ( UI ) or using the command line `aws ec2 modify-volume --volume-id ID_OF_DEVICE --size NEW_SIZE` ([modify volume command line documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-volume.html))

You still need to tell the operating system that you want to    *allocate more space* to the partition ( in this case the root partition `/`)
So the correct sequence to get it work is as shown:

**Extend the partition in a partition table to fill available space**

**(1)** `sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/expand-linux-partition.html

**Expand an ext2, ext3, ext4 file system**

**(2)**`sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1`

More on [AWS recognizing expanded volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Comment: This should be the solution accepted, as the command that you were missing is sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1, @Amit Khandelwal

Comment: In my case, `resize2fs` was throwing `Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/xvda1`. But when I used `xfs_growfs`, it worked fine.

Comment: The answer above has to do with `ext` file systems. In your case, the file system was `XFS`, which is the reason it worked. More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Answer (score 5):

**My solution**:

I don't know about you guys but I was able to add 30GB to my original 8GB Ubuntu EC2 instance and then I went to EC2 Console Manager and right clicked on my **Instance**, then pressed **Reboot**.

Once I rebooted and SSH'ed back into the server I typed `df -h` and saw that my root partition (`/dev/xvda1`) was of size 38GB.

Comment: Please only add answers in answer, if you have another question, ask it using the ask question interface.

Comment: Same thing happened for me. I was a few days away from giving up and going through all that AWS documentation to increase my root, when my server crashed. I rebooted it and suddenly the extra GBs I had already added to the instance had been added to my root partition. Best server crash I've ever had.

Comment: Same for me - reboot and get your extra GBs.

Comment: I also faced the same. Just rebooted and it worked for me

Comment: Same here - I tried following all the steps, but they didn't work. It wasn't until I rebooted that I saw the increase.

Answer (score 0):

Have funin 9 steps...........

Detach root volume and take snapshot of root volume for safer side and resize it.Once resizied, mount this volume to your_instance under /dev/sda1
ensure filesystem is fully expanded to root volume by running “lsblk” and “df -h” commands.
    If change is not reflected run, “resize2fs -f ”

Further details refer,

[Steps to increase the root volume](https://kalaivairamuthu.wordpress.com/2017/07/13/9-easy-steps-to-increase-your-root-volume-of-aws-instance/)

Comment: Perhaps you could summarize the steps in the link you provided here. That way if the link ever goes dead your answer will still be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comments stephen. I think now its useful.