# AWS EC2 - Attach Larger Volume with run-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I'm having difficulty launching an EC2 instance and increasing the size of the root partition in a single command with `aws ec2 run-instances`:

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
--image-id ami-0b33d91d \
--count 1 \
--instance-type m3.2xlarge \
--key-name my_key \
--security-group-ids "sg-xxxxxxx" \
--ebs-optimized \
--block-device-mapping "[ { \"DeviceName\": \"/dev/sda1\", \"Ebs\": { \"VolumeSize\": 120 } } ]"
```

The instance launches, and I can see the new 120GB volume listed (though not as root) in the console, but then the instance immediately stops (not terminates). I've tried renaming the DeviceName property per [these conventions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html), This is a temporary instance that I'm going to launch, do stuff, then terminate. Maybe I need to run `create-volume` first and then attach it with a separate series of commands? The AWS documentation seems to be all over the place on this and I can't find a clear explanation, though I've come across a few links [here](https://alestic.com/2009/12/ec2-ebs-boot-resize/) and [here](http://blog.xi-group.com/2014/06/small-tip-use-aws-cli-to-create-instances-with-bigger-root-partitions/). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465831/aws-ec2-root-volume-increase-expanding-elastic-root-volume-on-aws-ubuntu-instan) suggests resizing the partition but I'm not sure if that's what I need to do. As far as I can tell, the `m3.2xlarge` instance type has EBS available. Am I naming the partition incorrectly? Is something in this configuration causing the stoppage of the instance?

**EDIT**

After the instance stops itself, I get the follow as part of the response to `describe-instances`:

```
"BlockDeviceMappings": [
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Status": "attached", 
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                            "VolumeId": "vol-xxxx", 
                            "AttachTime": "2017-03-05T00:57:23.000Z"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1", 
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Status": "attached", 
                            "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                            "VolumeId": "vol-xxxx", 
                            "AttachTime": "2017-03-05T00:57:23.000Z"
                        }
                    }
                ], 
                "Architecture": "x86_64", 
                "StateReason": {
                    "Message": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown", 
                    "Code": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown"
                }, 
                "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
                "VirtualizationType": "hvm", 
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
```

Comment: Does the instance launch correctly if you omit the `--block-device-mapping` command parameter? (all other parameters remain the same). Also, on the stopped instance, what does the "state transition reason" say?

Comment: @MattHouser thanks for the response. The instance launches fine without --block-device-mapping. State transition reason is empty, i.e. `"StateTransitionReason": "",`. The StateReason prop, after the instances stops itself, reads: `"StateReason": {
                        "Message": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown", 
                        "Code": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown"
                    }, `. Very confusing, seems like the instance is shutting itself down. For good measure I'm going to post some more of the response in an edit in my question.

Comment: So the OS may be triggering the shutdown. Look at the instance console log to see if there is anything mentioned there.

Comment: Also try using `/dev/xvda` instead of `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: @MattHouser that worked. You are a genius sir, thank you. I wasn't aware of the PV vs HVM (Paravirtual VS Hardware VM) differential. For anyone reading this thread, [this article](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-ami-hvm-vs-pv-paravirtual-amazon/) is a pretty decent explanation of the difference and what you should be aware of when choosing an instance type. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're running into the same problem that this SO question is having:

https://serverfault.com/questions/615188/aws-t1-to-t2-migration-client-instanceinitiatedshutdown-on-new-t2-instance

Your instance is an HVM instance and wants to use `/dev/xvda` as the root device. However, you're specifying `/dev/sda1`. This is (a) creating a secondary volume instead, but then (b) preventing the instance from launching because that's a PV-related device rather than HVM.

So, as a solution, use `/dev/xvda` as the device name instead. Like the following command line:

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
  --image-id ami-0b33d91d \
  --count 1 \
  --instance-type m3.2xlarge \
  --key-name my_key \
  --security-group-ids "sg-xxxxxxx" \
  --ebs-optimized \
  --block-device-mapping "[ { \"DeviceName\": \"/dev/xvda\", \"Ebs\": { \"VolumeSize\": 120 } } ]"
```